# Boostrap 3 - thumbnail images alignment problem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

how to align them in a row with equal height.

[image]

```html
<div id="about-page-contain">
    <div class="">
      <div class="row equal">
        <div class="wwd">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/plots">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/be71f72e-b2e6-4dab-8dd4-8bc4d48365b8.jpg" alt="PLOTS" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>PLOTS</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/flats">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/ff74dcc3-71b4-4d35-b53b-77c6c36a0947.jpg" alt="FLATS" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>FLATS</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/farm-land">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/06fdde52-b169-45eb-a96a-ec1dd07f15e5.jpg" alt="FARM LAND" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>FARM LAND</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/development-sites">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/45d18935-9220-41ed-8f58-4aa3a16be8a8.jpg" alt="DEVELOPMENT SITES" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>DEVELOPMENT SITES</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/development-lands-for-plots">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/d85c0a59-2d35-4f24-830b-8cfe606f8caf.png" alt="DEVELOPMENT LANDS FOR PLOTS" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>DEVELOPMENT LANDS FOR PLOTS</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/independent-houses">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/5d265aad-31ef-4285-94a3-3aaeb0111e7a.jpg" alt="INDEPENDENT HOUSES" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>INDEPENDENT HOUSES</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/outrate-lands-for-appt-&amp;-plots">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/8d3cfcec-5415-422c-8426-665271216009.jpg" alt="OUTRATE LANDS FOR APPT &amp; PLOTS" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>OUTRATE LANDS FOR APPT &amp; PLOTS</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/commercial-properties">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/707cc088-4383-4423-8172-2fb2d9efa46d.jpg" alt="COMMERCIAL PROPERTIES" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>COMMERCIAL PROPERTIES</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/independent-villas-in-prime-locations">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/c2a9b09c-94bd-43ee-92ae-db4c587dd8eb.jpg" alt="INDEPENDENT VILLAS IN PRIME LOCATIONS" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>INDEPENDENT VILLAS IN PRIME LOCATIONS</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="hyderabad/construction-contract">
                  <img src="/public/uploadfiles/images/5f253c56-7f4d-4e61-9359-f5b2f7748443.jpg" alt="CONSTRUCTION CONTRACT" style="">
                  <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p>CONSTRUCTION CONTRACT</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. You have a class of wwd that we cannot see.  Is that applying some styles of some sort?
2. Each image has a blank style="" class.  Why is that there?
3. If I remove the link to the bootstrap styles I do not see any difference in applied styles.
4. the image sizes of your images can affect the layout and there are no actual links to the image so it makes it difficult to reproduce. Include the full links in your example to make it easier to reproduce.
   I [created a codepen](https://codepen.io/raddevus/pen/yLaoEqR) with a fake image but I don't see the issue you are seeing.

   ```
            <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="hyderabad/flats">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.r9MVqtg3zlXjdKLjkrZ04QHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt="DEVELOPMENT SITES" style="" width="100px">
          <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
            <p>FLATS</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   ```

[How about this example](https://codepen.io/raddevus/pen/PoGKaXJ)?

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.r9MVqtg3zlXjdKLjkrZ04QHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="100px">
      </a>
   </div>
   
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.r9MVqtg3zlXjdKLjkrZ04QHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="100px">
      </a>
   </div>
   
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.r9MVqtg3zlXjdKLjkrZ04QHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="100px">
      </a>
   </div>
   
   <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.r9MVqtg3zlXjdKLjkrZ04QHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" width="100px">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```